# How to set level treatment for Dunnett in R

Tags: r

So the code works just fine, but it uses the first level of treatment which is ABA; however, I need to set it as my variable Control. Is there a way to do that, or should I just rename my variables to get my Control first?

```
summary(plant) 
library(multcomp) 
grow<-glht(mod4,linfct = mcp(Type = "Dunnett"), 
alternative = "greater") 
summary(grow)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with the `contrMat` function:

```
library(multcomp)
fit <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)
groups <- table(iris$Species)
# setosa versicolor  virginica 
#     50         50         50 
contrastMatrix <- contrMat(groups, base = 2) # 2 <=> versicolor
glht(fit, linfct = mcp(Species=contrastMatrix), alternative='less')
```

---

```
> glht(fit, linfct = mcp(Species=contrastMatrix), alternative='less')

     General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: User-defined Contrasts

Linear Hypotheses:
                            Estimate
setosa - versicolor >= 0       0.658
virginica - versicolor >= 0    0.204
```